# Figures about android app size

Tags: size, android

I'm making a party games which contains many games, so the size of the application may be "relatively big". So i was wondering the maximum size for a game not to have any problem, because i know some people who don't download any games above ~8-10mo. Are there many people like this?

That's why i'm looking for some figures about that. I looked on the dashboard of google, but there is nothing, and i don't know which kind of key words i can use on google for that (i tried some things, but i found nothing).

Thanks

Comment: Nowadays, people do seem to care less about larger applications as RAM is cheap, and many devices ship with far more than the average user needs.  That being said, it's not an excuse to overload apps with huge graphics and stuff.  You should still try as hard as you can to optimize everything, including your app size, to be as small as possible.  For what it's worth, the largest games I've seen are the likes of Clash of Clans or Plants Vs Zombies.  Those are in the ~200MB area.  And that's WAY too big.  Unless you're writing something of that level, you should stay WELL below that.

Comment: yeah thoses game sizes are too much.
In fact, the problem is : let's say i have 20 mini-games and my app is like 15mo. Maybe for many people 15mo is a psychological threshold and then, it may be better to have 18 mini-games with a size of 14mo to get more download

Comment: I wrote an app once that was a launcher for a collection of smaller apps.  I found the trick is to reuse as many resources as possible.  Each one of those programs on their own would have been about 2MB.  But bundled and sharing, the entire thing, with 6 apps, is about 4MB.